# split list to N sublist and assign to n variables

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Hello i have big list of numbers and i want to split the list to N number and assign each part to a variable, i figure out how to split the list but how can i assign the sublists to same N variables

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

def getSublists(lst,n):
    subListLength = len(lst) // n
    list_of_sublists = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst), subListLength):
        list_of_sublists.append(lst[i:i+subListLength])
    return list_of_sublists

va = getSublists(l,3)
va1 = va[0]
print(va1)
```

Comment: can I write each part to a file without dynamic naming?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: i'm trying to load large file of numbers and split it to N , then handle each part , separately

Comment: *"can I write each part to a file without dynamic naming?"* Yes. You can use the list of lists `va` directly.

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to split your lists is:

```
# Define a segment length, n:
n = 5
# Create a list of lists:
sublists = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(l),n)]
```

Now you want to assign the sublists to variables? I'm going to assume you have a class you want to assign them to...
For example, we make a class called Lists() and we create a method that takes a list of lists, and a list of strings to name each list. The setattr command can then be used to set named variables within the class.

```
class Lists:
    def assignNames(self,lists,names):
        for lst,name in zip(lists,names):
            setattr(self,name,lst)
```

We would use it like so:

```
listClass = Lists()
names = ['a','b','c'] # one name for each sub-list.
listClass.assignNames(sublists,names)
```

Then you can access the values like so:

```
listClass.a
listClass.b
listClass.c
```

Does this achieve what you want?

Truth be told, the best option is just to stick with a dictionary or a list of lists. Even a named tuple would do. Often the more complicated route is not the best answer!

**Edit:**
Based on your comment:

> i'm trying to load large file of numbers and split it to N , then
> handle each part , separately

You have two things you can do:

1. Do the same thing to each sub-list:

```
results = []
for lst in sublists:
    # do something with lst.
    # This will repeat for each lst in sublist.
    # For example, taking the sum of each sublist:
    sum = np.sum(lst)
    # and appending it to a results list...
    results.append(sum)
```

2. Do something different to each sub-list and access them separately:

```
np.sum(sublist[0]) # do something with this
np.mean(sublist[1]) # and every sublist you need to access
np.amax(sublist[2]) # individually...
```